# How to print receipt on network printers using epson device sdk for android?

Tags: android, printing, epson

I am using epson device sdk (android) for printing receipt on smart printer. From my master printer other network printers are connected. I want to print receipt on all connected network printer, i found no way to implement this on provided epson document as well. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an Android app which prints on EPSON printers connected via Bluetooth. 
You can find more about it here: http://programminglife.io/android-epson-bluetooth-printer-connection/
The only change you have to make is to open a socket connection to an IP rather than a connection via Bluetooth.

Comment: can you please help me with the source code for wifi printing ?